# Getting next value of groupby after explode with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to get the first non-null value of the list inside each row of `Emails` column to write to the `Email_final1` then get the next value of the list inside each row of `Emails`, if there is one, to `Emails_final2` otherwise to write `Emails2` value to `Emails2_final` if not blank and doesn't equal 'Emails' otherwise leave `Emails_final2` blank. Lastly if a value from `Emails 2` was written to `Emails_final1` then make `Emails_final2` `None` I have tried many different ways to achieve this to no avail here is what I have so far including pseudo-code:

My Current Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Emails': [['jjj@gmail.com', 'jp@gmail.com', 'jc@gmail.com'],[None, 'www@gmail.com'],[None,None,None]],
                   'Emails 2': ['sss@gmail.com', 'zzz@gmail.com','ccc@gmail.com'],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2,3]},
                  index=['falcon', 'dog','cat'])
df['Emails_final1'] = df['Emails'].explode().groupby(level=0).first()
#pseudo code
df['Emails_final2'] = df['Emails'].explode().groupby(level=0).next()  #I know next doesn't exist but I want it to try to get the next value of 'Emails' before trying to get 'Emails 2 values.
```

Desired Output:

```
         Emails_final1      Emails_final2  
falcon   jjj@gmail.com      jp@gmail.com                
falcon   www@gmail.com      zzz@gmail.com                
falcon   ccc@gmail.com      None
```

Any direction of how to approach a problem like this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks a bit messy but it works. Basically, we keep a boolean mask from the first step in filling "Emails_final1" and use it in the second step to fill "Emails_final1".

To fill the second column, the idea is to use `groupby` + `nth` to get the second elements and if they don't match the previously selected emails; keep it (for example for the first row) but if it doesn't select from "Emails 2" column, unless it was already selected before (for example in the 3rd row):

```
exp_g = df['Emails'].explode().groupby(level=0)
df['Emails_final1'] = exp_g.first()
msk = df['Emails_final1'].notna()
df['Emails_final1'] = df['Emails_final1'].fillna(df['Emails 2'])
df['Emails_final2'] = exp_g.nth(1)
df['Emails_final2'] = df['Emails_final2'].mask(lambda x: ((x == df['Emails_final1']) | x.isna()) & msk, df['Emails 2'])
```

The relevant columns are:

```
        Emails_final1  Emails_final2
falcon  jjj@gmail.com   jp@gmail.com
dog     www@gmail.com  zzz@gmail.com
cat     ccc@gmail.com           None
```

Comment: @enke in the `.mask(lambda x: ((x == df['Emails_final1']) | x.isna()) & msk, df['Emails 2'])` is the df['Emails 2'] the default value for anything that mask masks? Am I understanding that?

Comment: @JustinBenfit it's used to replace the values where the condition is True; in this case, it's only the second row

Comment: @enke one more question if that' ok. I don't understand the usage of `msk`. It looks like it just returns true 137 times (one for each value in 'Emails_final1' that isn't null. Is it just to have a list of 137 trues so you can show that the corresponding value at each index position of  'Emails_final1' isn't null?

Comment: @JustinBenfit it returns True if an "Emails_final1" value was filled with an "Emails" value in the first step. Notice how it returns False for the last row. The idea is, we want to exclude rows such as the last row (which already used their "Emails 2" value in the previous step) when filling in "Emails_final2". You can see the difference by removing it from `mask` in the example.